# Could I use OpenNLP without machine learning?

Tags: nlp

I have a straightforward task of determining the sentence structure, specifically to identify if a sentence written in plain English is in the "present simple" tense and I want to write a small `java` program without using machine learning.

I know that I can use [OpenNLP](https://github.com/apache/opennlp) library for that, but it seems that library requires already trained model to check plain text.

Can I use `OpenNLP` library without machine-learning? I have heard about rule-based approach, could it help here?

Comment: Virtually every standard task in NLP (e.g. tokenizing, POS tagging) relies on ML nowadays. Do you mean that you don't want to use ML at all, or that you don't want to train a model yourself? Because OpenNLP certainly has pretrained models that you could use easily.

Comment: @Erwan I've checked some already existed models and they are quite large ~ 400mb. I want to create a small plugin that could be distributed among clients. The plugin size should be relatively small (~ 100KB).

Comment: If small models exists, I can get them, why not, but I thought that some algorithm exists that could give relatively precise results (I don't need 100%).

Comment: Ok I see, then in this case I think that the key is to use a traditional model which does not require embeddlings and/or DL. For example TreeTagger was used a lot for POS tagging and lemmatization. But this is still ML and the model would be a few MB at least.

Comment: @Erwan thanks, I'll check. What do you think, to frame this as an answer? I would accept it. Maybe it will be useful for somebody else.